# ASP Validation Expression Required For an Optional full stop and characters with limits of character

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, asp-classic

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]*)?$"
```

above is my validation expression, working fine for characters and accepting "full-stop(.)", I just want to limit characters, tried a lot but the not succeed.

Comment: What do you mean by limiting characters?  Are there characters that you want to allow? Do you want to limit the length of your expression?

Comment: Please let us know what exactly you need. And best is to provide some example valid and invalid input strings.

Comment: one full stop and alphabets and lower & upper bound of characters limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing expression should not be accepting the string "full-stop(.)" as it doesn't have any indicators that would allow the dash `-` character.

**Ensure Characters Are Properly Escaped**

Currently, your parentheses characters are not being escaped and since they are "special" within Regular Expressions, you'll need to do so by using `\(` and `\)` respectively.

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*\(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]*\)?$"
```

**Applying Ranges To Character Sets**

If you only want to allow a specific number of a certain character, you can replace your `*` with `{min,max}` to explicitly allow a certain range of values :

```
// This would allow between 1-4 letters, followed by an optional set of parentheses
// that contain a period and 1-4 letters (e.g. full(.test), lol(.jk), etc.)
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\)?$"
```

**Allowing Additional Characters**

Likewise, if you want to allow different characters, you can define these within your character set groupings `[...]`. For instance if you wanted to allow dashes to be included as well as letters, you would use :

```
// The explicitly escaped "\-" within your character groups indicates that 
// you want to allow dashes within your strings
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\-]*\(\.[a-zA-Z\-]*\)?$"
```

**Limiting Overall String Length**

You can append a section that looks like the following within your Regular Expression to handle limiting the overall length of the expression itself :

```
// The leading ^(?=.{min,max}$) section will define a constraint that the
// overall expression must be between min and max characters to be valid
ValidationExpression="^(?=.{min,max}$){your-expression-here}$"
```

So if you wanted to limit your expression to only accept between 8 and 12 characters total, you could use :

```
ValidationExpression="^(?=.{8,12}$)[a-zA-Z\-]*\(\.[a-zA-Z\-]*\)?$"
```

Comment: well there is an issue in this expression

Comment: ^(?=.{8,12}$)[a-zA-Z\-]*\(\.[a-zA-Z\-]*\)?$

if I put 8 character without (.) it allows post back.... I want mendatory full stop in with english alphabets only

Comment: Do you want the parentheses to actually be in the string or not? Your current example doesn't have them escaped so the second entire group `(\.[a-zA-Z\-]*)?` would be optional. If you don't actually want the parentheses and want to allow an 8-12 length alphabetic string that allows periods and dashes, you could use : `^[a-zA-Z\.\-]{8,12}$`

Comment: I just need  6 to 20 length input that contains alphabets and must one dot in it. may be I'm not explaining well.

Comment: Alright. If you need a string that is between 6-20 characters and consists only of alphabetic characters and a single dot, you could use `^(?=.{6,20}$)[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$` This would require at least one or more letters, followed by a dot a some point and then one or more additional characters (overall length between 6-20). You can [see an example of some output here](http://i.imgur.com/uFjCr0z.png).